# How can i dispose or close a listen function from Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, zip

**Flutter**

i have this listen function into `stful` which i need to close it when press on the back button

```
    class Test extends StatefulWidget {
      const Test({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _TestState createState() => _TestState();
    }
    
    class _TestState extends State<Test> {
    
      handleDelete(){
    
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("handleCountM").limit(1).snapshots().listen((value) {
          value.docs.forEach((element) {
            element.reference.delete();
          });
        });

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

i have no idea how could i stop it into `dispose()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("handleCountM").limit(1).snapshots();

late StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> streamSubscription;
  

void handleDelete() {
    streamSubscription = myStream.listen((value) {
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        element.reference.delete();
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    streamSubscription.cancel(); //Cancel your subscription here.
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Your other alternative, would be to use a streambuilder, and it'll handle the subscription and termination for you.

Comment: thanks a lot huthaifa but i don't use null safety version what should i use instead late?

Comment: Just remove the word `late`.

Comment: And read about null safety and start using it :) Lot's of work by the team was put into it, for many very good reasons, which are worth diving into :)

Answer (score 0):

The `listen()` method returns a [`StreamSubscription`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html) which has a [`cancel()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-async/StreamSubscription/cancel.html) method which cancels the subscription. After a call to this method the subscription no longer receives events.

Have a look at this [article](https://newbedev.com/stop-listening-to-snapshot-updates-in-cloud-firestore-in-flutter) which shows how to:

1. Store the `StreamSubscription` object in the state in order to be able cancel subscription on dispose.
2. Call the `cancel()` method in `dispose()`